WPF Passing an object to a data binding parameter
I have created a class inheriting Binding called SettingsBindingExtension. The constructor takes an object of a custom type ISettingsCategory, and a string.
In my XAML, I want to be able to set the content of an element using a declaration such as
Content="{settings:SettingsBinding ISettingsCategoryObject SomeString}"

whereas, ISettingsCategoryObject is a reference to some instance of an object.
Perhaps this isn't even possible, but if it were I don't know what the proper syntax would be.
I've tried a couple ways to try and couple something like <categories:SettingsCategory> into the content assignment, but to no avail.

It is unclear why this is supposed to be a class derived from Binding. You probably want to write a regular MarkupExtension. Note that the Binding class is also derived from MarkupExtension.

In XAML you create instances via markup. Now, if you're custom binding class has a property you can set it using object notation (nesting), Or you define the parameter as a resource and use StaticResource to pass it to your custom binding. It would be much easier to use MultiBinding. That way you can provide C# objects, but multiple opposed to the single of a normal Binding. An IMultiValueConverter enables to process all binding values to produce an output. It looks like you are trying to reinvent MultiBinding (the wrong way).
